# Screen capture of USB connected CE device

Tags: video, windows-ce, capture

Does anyone know if there's a tool to capture a video from a CE device (like [this](http://memor.datalogic.com/))? I used the Windows CE Remote Zoom-in to capture stills, but for presentation purposes I would like to show moving images. The devices is connected a pc using USB.

I've tried using a webcam, but I have to move the device around all the time to scan products.

Comment: When You already make mention of Datalogic and Memor, We are also looking for application for warehouse and material accounting.
If yours can used for these purpose, Can I contact you.

Answer (score 0):

I used this http://www.mymobiler.com/ for a while, dunno if it works for Windows CE though. I know there was another program that I have used, but I can't remember it's name.

Comment: Just tried it. It only works with windows mobile... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

A friend has used one of [THESE](http://www.pinnaclesys.com/PublicSite/us/Products/Consumer+Products/Dazzle/Dazzle+Video+Archiving/Dazzle+Video+Creator+Plus+HD.htm) to do something very similar in the past.